# java: hangman game repeating letters

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer, chars

I´ve got a logic problem with a hangman project, it takes an letter from the user and searches if that letter is contained within the secret word. The problem is the way I´ve programmed it, if there are several occurrences of the letter the user guessed within the secret word. it will just go through and denote them all. Which is not what I want, I only want it to update the status of correctly guessed letter one at a time.

I tried some different stuff like setting a break after `status(guessCh,` but then the iterator will just go to the first occurrence where the letters match and stop there.

any simple fix to this?

```
private void compare(String str)
{
    guessCh = str.charAt(0);
    char secretCh = '0';
    for (int i = i2; i < secretWord.length(); i++)                                           // Cuts the secret word into individual chars to process. 
    {
        secretCh = secretWord.charAt(i);
//      Compare the two strings.
        if (guessCh == secretCh)                                                            
        {
            status(guessCh, i);                                                               // Sends the letter & placement to status().  
        }

    }

}
```

n

```
private String status(char guessCh, int placement)
{
/*  Update and return status. */

    if (guessCh >='A' && guessCh <= 'Z')
    {
        status = new StringBuffer(status).deleteCharAt(placement).toString();
        status = new StringBuffer(status).insert(placement,guessCh).toString();
        println("That guess is correct.");
        canvas.displayWord(status);
        return status;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could test for a prior solution using your status variable from inside your compare method.

```
    if (guessCh == secretCh && status.charAt(i) != secretCh)
    {
        status(guessCh, i);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The test for `status.charAt(i) != secretCh` makes it skip letters that have already been solved, and the `break` makes it stop whenever one new letter has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read (and understand), the basic problem you're facing is caused by the `for` loop in the compare method.

(Note, my examples are case sensitive, you will need to take that into account)

There are two basic approaches I can suggest...

The first is, match ALL occurrences with a single check...

```
private char guessCh;
private String secretWord;
private String status;
private String secretBuffer;

public TestStringCompare() {

    secretWord = "This is a test";
    // This is a copy of the secret word, this ensures that
    // we always have a copy of the original.
    secretBuffer = secretWord;
    status     = "______________";
    guessCh = 'i';

    compare("i");

}

private void compare(String str) {

    while (secretBuffer.contains(str)) {

        int foundAt = secretBuffer.indexOf(str);
        status(str.charAt(0), foundAt);
        // We want to remove the "guess" from our check string
        // so it doesn't cause a false positive in the future
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(secretBuffer);
        sb.replace(foundAt, foundAt + 1, "_");

        secretBuffer = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(secretBuffer);


    }

}

private String status(char guessCh, int placement) {
    /*  Update and return status. */

    if (Character.isLetter(guessCh)) {
        status = new StringBuffer(status).deleteCharAt(placement).toString();
        status = new StringBuffer(status).insert(placement, guessCh).toString();
        System.out.println("That guess is correct.");
        System.out.println(status);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Which would produce:

```
That guess is correct.
__i___________
Th_s is a test
That guess is correct.
__i__i________
Th_s _s a test
```

or, replace the first occurrence of the guess (which from what I understand is what you're after)

```
public class TestStringCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestStringCompare();
    }
    private char guessCh;
    private String secretWord;
    private String status;
    private String secretBuffer;

    public TestStringCompare() {

        secretWord = "This is a test";
        secretBuffer = secretWord;
        status     = "______________";
        guessCh = 'i';

        compare("i");

    }

    private void compare(String str) {

        if (secretBuffer.contains(str)) {

            int foundAt = secretBuffer.indexOf(str);
            status(str.charAt(0), foundAt);
            // Some where here you need to remove the "guess" character
            // to ensure that it doesn't get repeated...
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(secretBuffer);
            sb.replace(foundAt, foundAt + 1, "_");

            secretBuffer = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(secretBuffer);


        }

    }

    private String status(char guessCh, int placement) {
        /*  Update and return status. */

        if (Character.isLetter(guessCh)) {
            status = new StringBuffer(status).deleteCharAt(placement).toString();
            status = new StringBuffer(status).insert(placement, guessCh).toString();
            System.out.println("That guess is correct.");
            System.out.println(status);
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Which would produce this...

```
That guess is correct.
__i___________
Th_s is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is homework of some sort - but anyway, why not use [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)